# Windows Store app submission is non-compliant (not accepting applications submitted through the DreamSpark developer program)

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-10-universal, dreamspark

I submitted my app updates for certification, but the certification process failed:

> Thanks for your interest in Windows Store. **Unfortunately, at this
>   time, we are not accepting applications submitted through the
>   DreamSpark developer program.**  We apologize for any inconvenience this
>   may cause. We also encourage you to read a recent blog on how to make
>   your app more visible in the Store
>   (https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/15/give-your-apps-more-visibility-six-recommendations-for-2016)
>   to build quality apps that customers want. Please reach out to
>   Developer Support if you have any questions.
>
> Locations: Metadata

DreamSpark developers won't be able to submit apps to windows store?

PS: many people have the same problem - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f90fbf2-42a3-4c85-8fc3-6ac8bb06c173/is-app-submission-from-dreamspark-developers-postponed

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue tried to submit an update to my app posted 2 days ago. Along with this app discoverability on store is a huge issue.Exact search returns no results.These tactics might scare away devs.I might switch to android

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  At least if you do sign up to sell your apps it is only a one time fee not a subscription you pay once a year

Comment: @KenTucker so is MSFT planning to do away with free store license that it gave to student devs?

Comment: i have no idea what there plans are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message received is correct.  There have been issues with misuse of Dreamspark accounts that were causing severe issues with the Store.  However, we realize that many of you are not part of this activity and as such we can help you by contacting Developer Support.  Please contact them directly so that they have your account information and can get your apps set up for success!

Thanks

Jo

Windows App and Catalog Operations

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has happened even upon contacting them! Sad !